# Jenkins container pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am using a freestyle Jenkins job for one of the POC projects. When I execute the given code, it throws error in the console output. Can someone please help me with this?

```
podTemplate(label: 'any', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'git', image: 'alpine/git', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')

  ],
  volumes: [
    hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock')
  ]
  ) {
    node('any') {
        stage('Check running containers') {
            container('docker') {
                // example to show you can run docker commands when you mount the socket
                sh 'hostname'                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Error Logs

```
tmp/jenkins5203006702049827868.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins5203006702049827868.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to execute a Scripted Pipeline as a shell script (**Build** > **Execute Shell**) in your freestyle job. Create a Pipeline project and then execute this as a Pipeline script. See https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/.

Comment: Hi Aditya, when I am using pipeline script, i am getting a different error "ERROR: Cloud does not exist: kubernetes
Finished: FAILURE"

Comment: Apologies, at the moment I do not have sufficient knowledge about Kubernetes cluster setup with Jenkins. However, at the first glance, it looks like the Docker host is not configured properly in the Clouds section of Jenkins Global Configuration. You may update the question with this information and appropriate labels so that other members can help.

Comment: I also had similar error and this post had the answer: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53299